# xsl:sort doesn't work in JDK 1.6 / Default xalan 2.7.0

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

For some reason very simple xsl:sort doesn't work for me. (apologies if i am making silly mistake)

I am hitting this weird voodoo magic behavior in JDK 1.6 (checked my xalan version to be 2.7.0). the following xml, xslt, xsl:sort doesn't work when run from java.

In my code the xslt is compiled and cached and I get a Template each time to do transform.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stats>
    <matches>
        <match>
            <goal>10</goal>
            <goal>2</goal>
            <goal>30</goal>
            <goal>344</goal>
            <goal>59</goal>
            <goal>6</goal>
            <goal>27</goal>
            <goal>18</goal>
            <goal>999</goal>
        </match>
    </matches>
</stats>
```

And xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template name="min">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:element name="result">
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(.)" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="max">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:element name="result">
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(.)" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="tails"
            select="/stats/matches/match/goal" />
        <xsl:call-template name="min">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$tails" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="max">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$tails" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I **don't get the expected output** below in my java program:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>2</result>
<result>999</result>
```

--- edited added code for my test java program ----

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.transform.Templates;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class XsltTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("XsltTest");
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            Templates templates = tf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new File(
                    "src/main/resources/test.xsl")));
            Transformer tr = templates.newTransformer();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            tr.transform(new StreamSource(new File("src/main/resources/test.xml")), new StreamResult(sw));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(sw.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You code looks all-right and should work. Can you try explicitly specifying a `select` attribute in your sort (`<xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" />`)?

Comment: An unqualified "It doesn't work" is very obnoxious to people trying to help you. What result are you getting when you try that XSLT?

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for the suggestion. i tried explicitly specifying a select attribute. still it doesn't work. I am adding the java code is used for my test program.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this works as expected with Saxon 9.5. So I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. So either there's a bug in the version of Xalan you are using, or you are invoking it incorrectly. (If you told us how it was failing, rather than just saying 'it doesn't work', then we would have a clue.)

There's no plausible reason to be using Xalan these days other than the convenience of it being embedded in the JDK. It hasn't been updated for years and no-one fixes the bugs. It only offers XSLT 1.0 which severely limits what you can do. Switch to Saxon.